# In Chart.js and django, add data by clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, chart.js

I am trying to make a simple program that drawing line graph using Chart.js(ver2.7) and ajax.
This program is that when user click button, it can get new data from saved in the database, and then advance labels and data in graph one by one in real time.

I understand that I write as follows, but I tried many times what to write inside the function, but I could not implement it.

```
$("#id").click(function() {
});
```

Currently, I can display properly the chart before implementing function above.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var endpoint ='/api/chart/data';
var defaultData = [];
var labels = [];

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: endpoint,
    success: function (data) {
    labels = data.labels;　
    defaultData = data.defaults;
    setChart();
    },
    error: function (error_data) {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(error_data)
    }
});


function setChart() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of medals',
                data: defaultData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    ...etc
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    ...etc
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

graph.html

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  </div>
```

How should this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar previously like this (clearly I'm doing in on a change in the select field but you can call it however you want):

```
$('#id_target_select').on('change', function() {
    var info = [];
    info[0] = $('#id_language').val();
    info[1] = $('#id_regulation_select').val();
    info[2] = $('#id_target_regulation_select').val();
    info[3] = $('#id_paragraph_select').val();
    info[4] = $('#id_number_topics').val();
    $.ajax({
        url : "/ajax/radar_graph/",  // endpoint
        type : "GET", // http method
        data : { info : info }, // send data
        // handle success response
        success : function(json) {

            // Add graph
            var chartLabels = json.categories.map(function(e) {
                return e.name;
            })
            var chartValues = json.values.map(function(e) {
                return e;
            })

            var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
            var data = {
                labels: chartLabels,
                datasets: [{
                    "label" : json.startRegulation[0].name,
                    "data" : chartValues,
                    "fill" : true,
                    "backgroundColor":"rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)",
                    "borderColor":"rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                    "pointBackgroundColor":"rgb(255, 99, 132)",
                    "pointBorderColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBackgroundColor":"#fff",
                    "pointHoverBorderColor":"rgb(255, 99, 132)"
                }]
            }
            var options = {
                "elements":
                    {"line":{"tension":0,"borderWidth":3}
                    },
                scale  : {
                    ticks : {
                        min : 0,

                    }
                }
            }

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'radar',
                data: data,
                options : options,
            });
```